# render different layout (rather than the default one)in controller

Tags: layout, render

the case is as follow i create a module that save articles in DB and when the the saving is successfull i need to redirect the user to thanks page .the contoller render the default layout in the index method how i render another layout when the saving process is complete in save method ,my module structure is as follow
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function saveAction(){

         $request_type = $this->getRequest()->getPost('request_type');
         $title = $this->getRequest()->getPost('title');

         $contact = Mage::getModel('hyper_membership/membership');  
         $contact->setData('request_type',$request_type)
         $contact->setData('title',$title)

         try {
              $contact->save()
              $this->_redirect('*/*/success')
              return;
         }catch (Exception $e) {
              ...
              $this->_redirect('*/*/error')
              return;
         }
    }


public function successAction(){
     $this->loadLayout();
     $this->renderLayout(); 
}

public function errorAction(){
     $this->loadLayout();
     $this->renderLayout(); 
}
```

You can then add the success and error pages to your xml